# Clojure Tail Recursion with Prime Factors

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion, prime-factoring

I'm trying to teach myself clojure and I'm using the principles of Prime Factors Kata and TDD to do so.

Via a series of Midje tests like this:

```
(fact (primefactors 1) => (list))

(fact (primefactors 2) => (list 2))

(fact (primefactors 3) => (list 3))

(fact (primefactors 4) => (list 2 2))
```

I was able to create the following function:

```
(defn primefactors 
    ([n] (primefactors n 2))
    ([n candidate] 
        (cond (<= n 1) (list)
              (= 0 (rem n candidate)) (conj (primefactors (/ n candidate)) candidate)
              :else (primefactors n (inc candidate))
        )
    )
)
```

This works great until I throw the following edge case test at it:

```
(fact (primefactors 1000001) => (list 101 9901))
```

I end up with a stack overflow error.  I know I need to turn this into a proper recur loops but all the examples I see seem to be too simplistic and only point to a counter or numerical variable as the focus.  How do I make this recursive?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow. This is the first time I see someone writing Lisp who actually give ) their own lines :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a tail recursive implementation of the `primefactors` procedure, it should work without throwing a stack overflow error:

```
(defn primefactors 
  ([n] 
    (primefactors n 2 '()))
  ([n candidate acc]
    (cond (<= n 1) (reverse acc)
          (zero? (rem n candidate)) (recur (/ n candidate) candidate (cons candidate acc))
          :else (recur n (inc candidate) acc))))
```

The trick is using an accumulator parameter for storing the result. Notice that the `reverse` call at the end of the recursion is optional, as long as you don't care if the factors get listed in the reverse order they were found.

Comment: Thanks this is awesome it's the explanation I needed.

Comment: In Clojure, "recurse then reverse" is an antipattern: we have vectors, which append cheaply on the right, so it's better to build the list in the right order to begin with (and if you need a list rather than a vector out at the end, just `seq` it, which is much cheaper than reverse). But really, a lazy solution is much preferable to a tail-recursive solution: see my answer for a simple example.

Answer (score 5):

Your second recursive call already is in the tail positions, you can just replace it with `recur`.

```
(primefactors n (inc candidate))
```

becomes

```
(recur n (inc candidate))
```

Any function overload opens an implicit `loop` block, so you don't need to insert that manually. This should already improve the stack situation somewhat, as this branch will be more commonly taken.

The first recursion

```
(primefactors (/ n candidate))
```

isn't in the tail position as its result is passed to `conj`. To put it in the tail position, you'll need to collect the prime factors in an additional accumulator argument onto which you `conj` the result from the current recursion level and then pass to `recur` on each invocation. You'll need to adjust your termination condition to return that accumulator.

Answer (score 5):

The typical way is to include an accumulator as one of the function arguments. Add a 3-arity version to your function definition:

```
(defn primefactors
  ([n] (primefactors n 2 '()))
  ([n candidate acc]
    ...)
```

Then modify the `(conj ...)` form to call `(recur ...)` and pass `(conj acc candidate)` as the third argument. Make sure you pass in **three** arguments to `recur`, i.e. `(recur (/ n candidate) 2 (conj acc candidate))`, so that you're calling the 3-arity version of `primefactors`.

And the `(<= n 1)` case need to return `acc` rather than an empty list.

I can go into more detail if you can't figure the solution out for yourself, but I thought I should give you a chance to try to work it out first.

Answer (score 4):

This function really shouldn't be tail-recursive: it should build a lazy sequence instead. After all, wouldn't it be nice to know that `4611686018427387902` is non-prime (it's divisible by two), without having to crunch the numbers and find that its other prime factor is `2305843009213693951`?

```
(defn prime-factors
  ([n] (prime-factors n 2))
  ([n candidate]
     (cond (<= n 1) ()
           (zero? (rem n candidate)) (cons candidate (lazy-seq (prime-factors (/ n candidate)
                                                                              candidate)))
           :else (recur n (inc candidate)))))
```

The above is a fairly unimaginative translation of the algorithm you posted; of course better algorithms exist, but this gets you correctness and laziness, and fixes the stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

A tail recursive, accumulator-free, lazy-sequence solution:

```
(defn prime-factors [n]
  (letfn [(step [n div]
            (when (< 1 n)
              (let [q (quot n div)]
                (cond
                  (< q div)           (cons n nil)
                  (zero? (rem n div)) (cons div (lazy-step q div))
                  :else               (recur n (inc div))))))
          (lazy-step [n div]
            (lazy-seq
              (step n div)))]
    (lazy-step n 2)))
```

Recursive calls embedded in `lazy-seq` are not evaluated before iteration upon the sequence, eliminating the risks of stack-overflow without resorting to an accumulator.